# Hierarchy category subcategory (parentId) forum database design

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2014

I am making a forum database. The needed tables are the questions and the comments tables. The question table has an `IsDeleted` flag and the comments table has an `IsDeleted` flag (PS the comments table is based on the category - sub category hierarchy - each comment has a `ParentId` (if it's null then it's on the top of the hierarchy)).

I am wondering what would be suitable when I am deleting a comment and deleting a question. For example when I delete a question it's obvious that I will mark the question as `IsDeleted` (should I delete the comments also as `IsDeleted`?). But when I am deleting a comment should I mark only the current comment as `IsDeleted` or the current comment and all it's descendants?

PS: Please support your advice with some sample code :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, your question asks to "GIMMY THE CODEZ", but that doesn't work here 

and will get your queston down-voted and eventually closed. Please read 
[**How to Ask a Good Question**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
and find out how to use this site
[**Taking the Tour**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: @Vickel no I meant that the code design should be supported with some sample code...

Comment: You should ideally do the same way as if it was hard deletion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a database trigger and update posts under the thread (ParentId) as deleted easily.
Just use an AFTER UPDATE trigger and check if IsDeleted column updated or not. So you can update posts as deleted too under that thread

But if you have analysis like how many posts are deleted because of spam, etc. it is better to keep a reason for deletion column. Or simply do not update child posts but to check their statu, always read the parent beside (which is not performing good always)

Here is a sample trigger code for a two table solution

```
create trigger post_delete on thread after update 
as
begin

update post
set isDeleted = 1
where threadId in (
    select d.threadId
    from inserted i
    inner join deleted d
        on i.threadId = d.threadId
    where i.isDeleted = 1 and
          d.isDeleted is null
)
end
```

I am adding meta data for the second case where all posts are stored in single table and adding recursive CTE within modified trigger below
I hope it helps

```
create table Posts (
    PostId int,
    ParentId int,
    Title nvarchar(256),
    Text nvarchar(max),
    IsDeleted bit
)
```

Following [AFTER UPDATE SQL trigger](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-trigger-example-in-sql-server-2008.aspx) works for SQL table like above

```
create trigger posts_delete on posts after update 
as
begin

with tbl as (
    select d.PostId
    from inserted i
    inner join deleted d
        on i.PostId = d.PostId
    where i.IsDeleted = 1 and
            d.IsDeleted is null
), cte as (
    select * from Posts where PostId in (select PostId from tbl)
    union all
    select p.* 
    from Posts p
    inner join cte
        on cte.PostId = p.ParentId
)
update posts
set isDeleted = 1
where PostId in (
    select PostId from (
        select * from cte
    ) t
)
end
go
```

I tested the SQL script using following sample data

```
insert into Posts select 1, null, 'Triggers','',NULL
insert into Posts select 2, null, 'Databases','',NULL
insert into Posts select 3, 1, 'DDL Trigger','SQL',NULL
insert into Posts select 4, 3, 'What is DDL?','DDL',NULL

select * from Posts
update Posts set IsDeleted = 1 where PostId = 3
select * from Posts
```

Results are as follows

[image]

Comment: yea the question and the comments to it would be done easy but what about if a comment that has comments to it gets deleted? should I mark only it or all the others comments to it also as IsDeleted?

Comment: OK, I got the question better now. I'm also running a forum but it has two level hierarchy. So you can use a recursive query (recursive cte expression) http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/sql-server-recursive-query-with-recursive-cte.aspx to get all sub items within the trigger. So by starting from the deletedId you can get all childID's of it and update isDeleted columns of them. By the way, probably you are using single table. You can create a very similar one shown above

Comment: is there some way I can use the "with clause" to update my IsDeleted flag in the comments table?

Comment: I modified the answer and added a second table structure, a corresponding After Update Trigger with some test data. I hope this solves your issue

Answer (score 0):

We currently have a similar model in our database and I would suggest only setting IsDeleted for the thing the user deleted and not subordinate objects. Why? Restoration. If you mark comments as deleted when the user deletes a question, how do you properly restore the proper comments if you restore the question?